# How to start up a Kubernetes cluster using Rocket?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using a Chromebook Pixel 2, and it's easier to get Rocket working than Docker. I recently installed Rocket 1.1 into /usr/local/bin, and have a clone of the Kubernetes GitHub repo.

When I try to use `./hack/local-up-cluster.sh` to start a cluster, it eventually fails with this message:

```
Failed to successfully run 'docker ps', please verify that docker is installed and $DOCKER_HOST is set correctly.
```

According to the docs, k8s supports Rocket. Can someone please guide me about how to start a local cluster without a working Docker installation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set three environment variables before running `./hack/local-up-cluster.h`:

```
$ export CONTAINER_RUNTIME=rkt
$ export RKT_PATH=$PATH_TO_RKT_BINARY
$ export RKT_STAGE1_IMAGE=PATH=$PATH_TO_STAGE1_IMAGE
```

This is described in the [docs for getting started with a local rkt cluster](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/rkt#local-cluster).

Comment: Thanks for the doc link. Pretty sure this is exactly what I'm looking for, and just failed at Google :).

Answer (score 0):

Try running `export CONTAINER_RUNTIME="rocket"` and then re-running the script.